# Combination JavaScript, Websockets and Java

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, glassfish, netty

I'm new to Websockets and I want to make a multiplayer-Pong-game. I got it working using Javascript with websockets on the client side and a WebsocketEndpoint (Glassfish-Server) on the server side, but I was wondering if this is a good soldution. As far as I found out, it is very hard to push data to clients while using this combination. After some search I found out about the Netty Framework which is said to be a good solution for this kind of application. The thing is: During my research, I have never seen any JavaScript client to such a Netty Application. Is this possible?

In short:
What I want to achieve is:
- Using Javascript with websockets on client side
- Using Java on server side

Does anybody have experience with it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [Atmosphere js](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-Started-with-The-Atmosphere-Framework-and-WebSocket) it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generally described architecture sounds fine to me, namely a websocket server and a javascript websocket client. If you're happy with Glassfish, I would run with it.

You can also use Netty to implement the same thing, as it has excellent support for WebSockets and barring anything out of the oridinary with your Glassfish implementation, the same JavaScript client should work with a Netty WebSocket server.

If you decide to pursue the Netty server angle, take a look at the [Netty WebSocket example](http://netty.io/3.10/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx/server/package-summary.html). That example is for Netty 3 (which I am still on) but Netty 4 is the most widely used, and Netty 5 is the latest and greatest. The example supplies a basic javascript client, but as I said, if you have already written one, I would assume it will work seamlessly.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot. I have one more related question: Now, all the calculation of my game is done on one client and sent via server to the other client. I think, a better solution would be to calculate everything on the server and push the results to both clients (to prevent manipulation and keep both clients synchronized). To do that, I need a gameloop on server and push messages to clients. Do you have any experience how to achieve this? When using WebsocketEndpoint, I only have three methods: One on connection open, one on close and one when a message is received.

Comment: ?? You should have a server side send directive. (See the netty example) you can implement a timer to periodically send updates to all the clients, or on some other event. Websockets are bidirectional.

Comment: Oops I had a flaw in my mind. Of course, you are correct. I found a solution. Thank you very much.